# Is the Lord's coming (in the air) 1Th 4:14, 17 also called "the day of the Lord Jesus Christ"? 1 Cor 5:10?

Tags: second-coming, rapture

Does "the coming (parousia, 3952) of the Lord" 1Th 4:15 "in the air" 1Th 4:17b constitute "the day of Jesus Christ" Phil 1:6, "the day of Christ" Phil 1:10, 2:16; "day of our Lord Jesus Christ" 1 Cor 1:8, "day of the Lord Jesus" 1 Cor 5:5, 2 Cor 1:14 and/or judgement seat (968 Interlinear) of Christ Rm 14:10, 2 Cor 5:10?

Comment: No, it ends time. The millenium and the supposed 'tribulation ' are fictions.

Comment: @NigelJ, So Jesus was just referring to a fairy tale in Matthew 24:21,29 and Mark 13:24?

Comment: @Nijel, that is a rather surprising statement...references to support it by any chance? (because Jesus was rather direct in producing the prophecy)

Comment: I mean the 'millenium' and the 'tribulation' in their modern parlance, of course. The scriptural thousand years symbolises the Church Age as does the tribulations symbolic of one's passage through that time. What is fiction is the setting up on earth of a Kingdom ruled over by Christ. When the clear truth from every part of scripture is that his coming will end time and bring in a altogether New Creation.

Comment: "every part of scripture is that his coming will end time and bring in a altogether New Creation" Yes... *after* the 1000 years. No one denies that this is true(well, not me anyway), but it happens *after* the 1000 years, which are both literal and symbolic.

Comment: DV: This is a conjecture seeking opinions. It is possible that the question could be clarified to be hermeneutic but it would require a re-write of the question about the text, not about how the text might relate to a generic topic.

Answer (score 2):

The operative word here is θλῖψις (thlipsis) which occurs 45 times in the NT text.  The word is used in three distinct senses:

- historical tribulations such as those recorded in Acts 7:10, 11, 11:19, 14:22, 20:23, Phil 1:17, Col 1:24, 1 Thess 1:6, 3:3, 7, 2 Thess 1:4, 6, etc
- tribulations a general part of the Christian experience, eg, Matt 13:21, 24:9, Mark 4:17, John 16:21, 33, Rom 2:9, 5:3, 8:35, 12:12, 1 Cor 7:28, 2 Cor 1:4, 8, 2:4, 4:17, 6:4, 7:4, 8:2, 13, Eph 3:13, Phil 4:14, Heb 10:33, James 1:27, Rev 1:9, etc.
- "Great Tribulation" occurs just four times in Matt 24:21, Acts 7:11, Rev 2:22, 7:14.  However, it is also referenced in Matt 24:29 and probably in Mark 13:19, 24.

The fact that the term "great trubulation" is used of general nature of a particularly intense kind in Acts 7:11, and Rev 2:22 means that such periods of intense tribulations will break out against the Christian community from time to time and are not unique.  The (eschatological) Great Tribulation at the end of time,, which is popular in some circles, is only referenced twice:

- in the "synoptic apocalypse", ie, in Matt 24:21, 29, Mark 13:19, 24
- Rev 7:14.

From these we can deduce only the following rather meager predictions:

- The great (eschatological) tribulation is associated with the abomination of desolation, Matt 24:15-18.  See appendix below.
- The great tribulation will be cut short to that there will be some righteous left to save, Matt 24:22
- Immediately after the great tribulation the sun, moon and stars will be darkened following which the Son of Man appears in the clouds of heaven with Power and great glory to gather the saints from the four corners of the world. Matt 24:29-31.
- Those who survive the great tribulation are those who have washed their robes in the blood of the lamb, etc.  Rev 7:14.

**Conclusion**

If we associate (not all do!) the "meeting the Lord in the air" (1 Thess 4:16, 17) with "the Son of Man appearing in the clouds of heaven with power and great glory with the angels" to gather the saints (Matt 24:29-31), it appears that the great tribulation and its associated abomination of desolation occurs only a short while before the second advent of Christ.

**APPENDIX - Abomination of Desolation**

In the Greek NT, the phrase βδέλυγμα τῆς ἐρημώσεως (= “abomination of desolation”) has a pivotal occurrence in both first century events and apocalyptic events that overlap.  The word ἐρημώσεως (eremoseos) is from the root word ἐρήμωσις (erémósis) which BDAG defines as, the “state of being made uninhabitable, devastation, destruction, depopulation”.  This word only occurs in the following places in the NT:

- Matt 24:15, “abomination of desolation which was spoken by Daniel the prophet …”
- Mark 13:14, “abomination of desolation standing where it ought not to be …”
- Luke 21:20, “when you see Jerusalem surrounded by armies, then know that its desolation has come near.”

The “abomination of desolation” (or similar phrase) occurs elsewhere only in Daniel 8:13, 9:27, 11:31, 12:11.  The phrase might be more helpfully translated, “depopulating sacrilege”.  It is also alluded to in several other places as we shall see. Let us list the characteristics of the abomination of desolation from these references.

- It causes the cessation of the “daily” (Heb: Tamid) usually understood to be the daily (or continual) sacrifice (Dan 8:13).  More correctly, it points to the ministry of Jesus our High Priest and His continual ministry in the heavenly sanctuary.
- It occurs because of rebellion (presumably of those supposed to be God’s people.  Non-Christians and non-Jews cannot rebel because they have not declared loyalty to God.) (Dan 8:13)
- It ushers in a period (“times of Gentiles” according to Luke 21:20-24) where the sanctuary and God’s people will be trampled underfoot (Dan 8:13, Rev 11:2)
- It is associated with a coming ruler (not Messiah), presumably, the antichrist (Dan 9:27); in 2 Thess 2:1-12 he is called the “man of lawlessness”, and, “son of destruction”.
- Dan 11:31 appears to equate the King of the North with the one who would abolish the “continual” (Heb: “Tamid”) and desecrate the temple fortress and thus depopulate the temple of worshipers.
- There are several time periods associated with the abomination of desolation: 2300 days until its end (Dan 8:13); 1290 days from its beginning (Dan 12:11); 42 months (Luke 21:20-24, Rev 11:2), 70 weeks (Dan 9:24-27).
- The abomination of desolation is to stand in the holy place (Hebrew idiom for either the temple or Jerusalem, Matt 4:5, 27:53, 24:15, Acts 6:13, 21:28) and is where this ruler does not belong (Mark 13:14).  This is the signal for those in Jerusalem to immediately flee and the immanent depopulation of Jerusalem of Christians.
- The abomination of desolation was in Jesus’ time still future (Matt 24:15).  (Therefore, this could not have been Antiochus Epiphanes.)

It is immediately obvious that Jesus applied this prophecy (at least in part) to the destruction of the temple (which occurred in 70 AD) that temporarily despoiled and depopulated Jerusalem, in his famous “Synoptic Apocalypse”.  But it is also obvious that Jesus intended far more than this from the numerous references in this sermon to the end of the world.  The question that prompted this sermon is a two-fold question (Matt 24:3) about both (a) the destruction of Jerusalem, and, (b) Jesus’ Second Advent.  Jesus’ response was to answer both questions simultaneously by giving a dual prophecy.  The advantage we have is to learn lessons from the destruction of Jerusalem and apply these to the remainder of Christian history since.  Thus, while some parts of Jesus’ final sermon are clearly apocalyptic, much has a dual application as we shall soon see.

In Jesus’ time, the abomination of desolation was fulfilled when the pagan Roman government (by its army) stood in Jerusalem and soon destroyed it by desecrating the temple and temporarily depopulating the city .  Apocalyptically and eschatalogically, Paul tells us what would happen in 2 Thess 2:3 & 4 - Let no one in any way deceive you, for it will not come unless the apostasy comes first, and the man of lawlessness is revealed, the son of destruction, who opposes and exalts himself above every so-called god or object of worship, so that he takes his seat in the temple of God, displaying himself as being God.  This uses the same language as Jesus’ sermon.  The “man of lawlessness” would precipitate the abomination of desolation by blasphemously trying to usurp the rights and prerogatives of God Himself by removing Christ from the heavenly sanctuary and the continual (Heb: “Tamid”) intercession He offers for us (1 Tim 2:5, Heb 4:14-16, 7:23-28, 8:1, 2, 9:1-28, 10:1-18) as our High Priest.

Thus we find that the little horn of Daniel 7, the (latter part) of the little horn of Daniel 8, the (latter part) of the king of the north that causes the abomination of desolation, the “man of lawlessness” in 2 Thess 2, and the sea beast of Rev 13, are all prophecies about the same medieval power that is blasphemous and sets itself against Jesus and His faithful people and persecutes Christ’s followers.

Comment: this entire doctrine must consider "the full" time period of Daniel Chapter 2. It cannot be stated that the second coming of the Christ (the stone cut without hands) is completed before the feet of mixed iron and clay (some strong and some weak). It is very clear that does not refer to the time of the latter first century but in fact speaks of the age in which we now find ourselves. In any case, Jerusalem was attacked a second time ending in AD 135. In our current age, we have no single ruling world government, what we have are some strong and some weak as predicted in Daniel Chapter 2.

Comment: @Adam - all true but the tribulation is not mentioned in Daniel 2 and neither is the abomination of desolation.

Comment: however, the misconception about the book of Daniel is that Chapter 2 is not the overall "big picture" for the rest of the book. Chapter 2 gives us the complete timeline from Nebuchadnezzar right down to the end of time. Therefore, the stone cut without hands points to the second coming of Christ and the final cleansing of the world from all evil. This means that the abomination of desolation in later chapters as well as the tribulation are absolutely a part of it . Just that they are not explored in detail until the later chapters. Nothing unusual about this in a literary sense.

Comment: Dottard - A couple of comments: Mt 24:29-30 occurs "after the tribulation." Rev 7:14 "coming (2064) out (1537) of" Note - erchomai (2064) followed by ek (1537), from or out of the Tribulation Rev.7:14 "having escaped from {a.t.}". Also, Rev 3:10 "I will also keep you from the hour of trial." I suggest that these are the "caught up" "great multitude" brought by the Lord to His Father 1Th 3:13. Ref NKJV, Interlinear, The Complete WordStudy Dictionary New Testament, ISBN 0-89957-663-X

Comment: @Adam - I agree.  It is just that nothing about this question can be answered from Daniel 2.

Comment: @hank - that is what I said in the 3rd dot point before the conclusion.  However, your point about Rev 3:10 could simply mean that they do not live through the great tribulation, that is, they die before it begins as many already have.

Comment: Dottard - I'm sorry I missed that - but my question was about the beginning of the Tribulation. What event causes the beginning of the 70th week of Daniel 9:27. I'm suggesting that the ""day of the Lord Jesus" 1 Cor 5:5, 2 Cor 2:14 happens at His "coming" 1Th 4:15 "Himself" 1Th 4:16 "in the air" 1Th 4:17b. Not His 2nd Advent when He comes to earth with His angels.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing comments, the short answer to the question of the Lord's coming (in the air) starts the Tribulation is NO. The event that starts the Tribulation is the 7 yr "covenant" Dan 9:27 between "the prince who is to come" Dan 9:26 (aka Antichrist, Muslim Mahdi) and "with many for one week" (Jews) Dan 9:27, Is 28:4-22 Ref: NKJV, AntiChrist Islam's Awaited Messiah, ISBN 1-4141-0440-5

Comment: Doddard - 6th bullet, I also suggest adding - also from the beginning, 1260 days of saints persecution of the Antichrist. Daniel 7:25b "Then the saints shall be given into his hand. For a time and times and half a time." Daniel 12:7b "it shall be for a time, times and half a time, and when the power of the holy people has been completely shattered , all things shall be finished."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The Lord's Coming (in the air) 1Th 4:14, 17 is "The Day of The Lord Jesus Christ"
1 Cor 5:10.

It Is "a Day Of (Heavenly) Light"  as opposed to "The Day Of The LORD" which is "a day of (earthly) Darkness. ie:

The Day Of CHRIST:

“Mystery” CHURCH: Designated as the “Heavenly” Day of CHRIST,
Which will be The Day of reward and consummation of our salvation (Philippians 1:6, 10; Philippians 2:16;
I Corinthians 1:8; II Corinthians 1:14).

Rightly Divided (2 Timothy 2:15) From “Things That Differ”

The Day Of The LORD:

Israel’s KINGDOM: Designated as the “Earthly” Day of The LORD,
which will be first of all a day of judgment to be followed by the establishment of the Kingdom (Isaiah 13:9 to 16;
Isaiah  24:21 to 23; Isaiah 26:20 and 21; Isaiah 34:1 to 35:10; Ezekiel 30:3; Joel 1:15; Joel 2:1 to 11; Amos 5:16 to 20; Obadiah 1:15 to 21; Zephaniah 1:14 to 18; Zephaniah 14:1 to 21; Malachi 4:1 to 6; Matthew 25:31 to 46; Acts 2:19 to 21)

Appreciate the opportunity...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: GRACE - Thanks for your answer - to which I concur.